# API images do not load in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, react-native, express

I am experiencing a problem when trying to load images that come from my API (Together with other data), but it is not appearing on the phone / emulator, it is not loaded.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image, StyleSheet, FlatList, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

import api from '../services/api';

export default function SpotList({ tech }) {
  const [spots, setSpots] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadSpots() {
      const response = await api.get('/spots', { // /spots?tech=tecnologia
        params: { tech }
      })

      setSpots(response.data);
      console.log(spots)
    }

    loadSpots();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Empresas que usam <Text style={styles.bold}>{tech}</Text></Text>

      <FlatList 
        style={styles.list}
        data={spots}
        keyExtractor={spot => spot._id}
        horizontal
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} //barra de rolagem
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View style={styles.listItem}>
            <Image style={styles.thumbnail} source={{ uri: item.thumbnail_url }}/>
            <Text style={styles.company}>{item.company}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.price}>{item.price ? `R$${item.price}/dia` : 'GRATUITO'}</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {}} style={styles.button}>
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Solicitar Reserva</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

When I run the console.log (spots) command, the terminal returns the URL to me normally.

```
[
  {
    "techs": [
      "ReactJS",
      "Node.js"
    ],
    "_id": "5f10b8e8ed571238cc9434ad",
    "user": "5f10b3afed571238cc9434ab",
    "thumbnail": "google-1594931431941.jpg",
    "company": "Google",
    "price": 68,
    "__v": 0,
    "thumbnail_url": "http://localhost:3333/files/google-1594931431941.jpg",
    "id": "5f10b8e8ed571238cc9434ad"
  }
]
```

When I open thumbnail_url through the browser, it displays the images as normal.

Comment: try with the IP address instead of 'localhost'

Comment: this happened on android9 (PIE) or greater, you need to make sure all URL is `https`, not `http`

Comment: The problem is not in the API, the data is arriving normally, but the image is not shown on screen

Answer (score 0):

Network images in React Native require a height and a width in order to display. You can either add these as separate props or pass them as styles.

Comment: I am passing height and width, still it is not shown

Answer (score 0):

try adding this is in styles
thumbnail:  {
width: 50,
height: 50,
}

u can find more about this here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/image

Comment: I was going through the styles below, but I tried to go directly now and it didn't work either, the image is not shown